# Struct pointer as function parameter with huge amount of data on embedded

Tags: c, pointers

is there any downside in general by using such a method in embedded when dealing with a huge amount of data. Just as an minimal illustration.

Let's say there exist a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    /*This struct has elements with a size of 80bytes*/
    int a;
    int b:
    /*...
    ...*/
    int n;
    
} theStructElements


typedef struct
{   
    theStructElements    elements[5000]
} theStruct_t

void myFcn(theStruct_t *pOut)
{
    for (uint32 i = 0; i< 3000; i++)
    {
        pOut.elements[i].a = x;
        pOut.elements[i].b = y;
        /*.....*/
        pOut.elements[i].n = z; 
    }
}

int main()
{
    static theStruct_t myList;
    myFcn(myList);
}
```

Let's also asume the function is called periodically each 40ms. The question is in general without mentioning any specific hardware platform.

Comment: The main disadvantage is that the size of embedded array is fixed to 5000.

Comment: Excepting the obvious syntax errors (in the actual code, not the shortened `...` parts), why do you think there would be any downsides? What are *your own* thoughts about the possible issues?

Comment: ... was intended just to illustrate that there are more elements in the struct

Comment: Members named `a` to `n` suggest 14 `int`'s in the `struct`... At 4 bytes each, that would be 56 bytes, not 80... Jus' sayin'... Anyway... it'd probably be faster to establish one instance of the struct with the values you want, then simply `memcpy()` 3000 times... If you're really clever, you could even work out how to "double" and "double double" to replicate bytes faster... (Why use `int a;` to `int n;`??? Why not use an array?)

Comment: This question cannot be answered because we don't know enough details about your use case. Your approach might be exactly what you need to do, or it might be completely wrong way to do it.

Comment: Your compiler might complain using default settings about putting large arrays on the stack. You could say that is a downside rather than dynamically allocating on the heap.

Comment: Generally speaking then passing structs through a pointer should be fine. However, I've experienced very bad ABI for small 8 bit microcontrollers where they specified that a number of struct members would get passed in various registers to the point where it became cumbersome and using a file scope variable resulted in faster code. But I think that's such an odd and special scenario that you may ignore it. And nobody who knows what they are doing use 8 bitters any longer.

Comment: @SimonGoater Array is not going to stack because `myList` is declared with `static`. Also, heap is often not used with embedded systems because of many uncertainties with it.

Comment: @user694733 Thanks for the info. I learn something new everyday....